# Tab bar doesn't appear with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a problem, with this code :
http://pastebin.com/4D6hmAQh

The title bar appears successfully (with the title aFaire) but the tab bar doesn't appear.

How to make the tab bar appear, programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overridden the `loadView` method of the `RootViewController` and you don't call the `[super loadView]` statement. However, the `UITabBarController` needs to initializes its `tabBar` through the `loadView` method. So you have to call `[super loadView]`.

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    // self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    self.title = @"aFaire";

    NSMutableArray *localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    firstViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"First";

    [localViewControllersArray addObject:firstViewController];

    self.viewControllers = localViewControllersArray;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
}
```